# React Redux Store values immediatly after dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'ts possible to get the store values immediately after dispatch in redux thunk ?
My component is like this :
...

```
const handleGetProduts = async() => {
 await props.getProducts()
 setResults(props.results)
 console.log('props after getProducts: ', props)
    }
```

...
And reducer is:

```
const initialState= {
 results: [],
 products: [],
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
 console.log(action)
 switch (action.type) {
 case 'GET_PRODUCTS_FULFILLED':
 return {
        ...state, results: action.payload.results
      }
 default:
 return state
    }
   }


export const getProducts = () => async dispatch => {
 console.log('Enter getProducts')
 const result = await dispatch({
 type: 'GET_PRODUCTS',
 payload: fetch('http://server.domaina.com').then(response => response.json())
  });
 return result;
};
```

Thank you

Comment: It might work, but this way, you have to worry about the action in your component. Also, your reducer would not be reusable. Better way is to use Action Creator.

Answer (score 1):

In functional components, you can use [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) hook to get the state from the store.

**However**
1. `console.log('props after getProducts: ', props)` will not print the latest products *immediately* as the state updates are asynchronous and you are logging in a handler. To see the updated products, put console log somewhere in the functional component.

2. Note `handleGetProduts` doesn't need to be async and you don't need to await for `props.getProducts()`.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

**useSelector ex**
export const ProductsComponent = () => {
  const products = useSelector(state => state.products)
  return <div>{products[0].name}</div>
}
```